# Apache 2.4 / SSL certificates error: AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I recently had to renew one of my SSL certificates on an Apache 2.4/Mod_ssl server.

I have 2 Vhosts, no SNI, each running on a separate NIC.
Until now the certificates were both Globalsign OrganizationSSL, one specific to an URL, the other one is a wildcard.
All this was running fine.

My client wanted to have an Extended Validation SSL. I downloaded the root CA and Intermediate cert required for this chain to operate.
But upon switching the certs, my Apache refuses to initialize the chain.

I have the following errors:

- Apache log: [ssl:emerg] [pid 7394:tid 140377904683136] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
- Vhost log: [ssl:emerg] [pid 7394:tid 140377904683136] AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain!

My Vhost SSL conf:

Vhost 1 (Organization SSL):

```
SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EDH:!DHE:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/organization.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.pem
```

Vhost 2 (Extended Validation SSL):

```
SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/gs_root_ca.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/extended_validation.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server2.key
```

I'm no SSL specialist, and I don't understand why Extended Validation and  Organization SSL certs cannot cohabit..

I tried to remove one Vhost and the other, it's working perfectly.
So I was forced to disable to least used vhost for my main production backoffice to work.

Have you ever encountered such error? Is it a normal behavior? What can I do to have both my sites running again?

Thanks for your expertise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it up incorrectly.

Let's recollect:

- **SSLCertificateKeyFile** loads the **private key** (you are doing this fine)
- **SSLCertificateFile** loads the **server certificate chain**. That is the server certificate and its signing CA's sorted from leaf (certificate) to root (higher lvl CA).
- **SSLCertificateChainFile** **is deprecated** in apache 2.4, so remove this one.
- **SSLCACertificateFile** loads the CAs for clients that will authenticate through SSL with client certificate. *THIS IS THE ONE YOU WANT TO USE FOR SSL CLIENT AUTH* then.

*Sidenote*: Your Ciphersuite seems very incorrect and insecure at first sight. Worth checking for a change in that one too.

**Edit** based on comments.
**For 2.4.6 and earlier you should**:

- **SSLCertificateFile** loads the **server certificate**.
- **SSLCertificateChainFile** loads the **server certificate CA chain**.
- **SSLCACertificateFile** loads the CAs for clients that will authenticate through SSL with client certificate. *THIS IS THE ONE YOU WANT TO USE FOR SSL CLIENT AUTH* then.

Comment: Thanks for all these infos.  
I saw somewhere that SSLCertificateChainFile was deprecated, but the article talked about apache 2.4.8 and I'm running 2.4.6 so I thought I was not affected.  
So I can concatenate my website cert, intermediate cert AND the globalsign root CA in the same file?  
Regarding SSLCACertificateFile, which cert should I enter here?  
Sorry if my questions are trivial, but I still don't understand clearly the expected certs in each directive... And thanks for your comment on the Ciphersuite, I'll look into it too!

Comment: Hello again,

I tried to concatenate the certs, but if I do a SSL check, I'm told that the chain is incomplete.

However if I run the extendedSSL vhost with my original conf and the second with the concatenated chain the server is running, and my SSL ratings are good (A- and B because incomplete chain).

Comment: let me adjust the reply for 2.4.6 then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! I'll try this and let you know.
In 2.4.6, can I concatenate the certs?

Comment: @J.Aublin Yes, SSLCertificateChainFile IIRC is sorted from root to leaf, but remember, just CA's. And SSLCACertificateFile is concatenated in order of preference.

Comment: So in SSLCertificateChain I put my root CA and website cert concatenated, but then  do I need SSLCACertificateFile?

Comment: @J.Aublin NO, can you read the answer please? It already says where the server certificate goes pre 2.4.8

Comment: My apologies, I got a little lost. But everything is OK now, thank you again for all these info!

Comment: @J.Aublin Then please mark my answer so the question does not keep showing up as unanswered.

Comment: A big warning note: `SSLCertificateChainFile` is still documented, supposed to be used, and yields no warning… but is silently ignored nowadays, causing startup errors. See [Debian #912277](http://bugs.debian.org/912277) for the story ☹